# Interfacing old system with new Angular 4 frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

We are in the process of converting our systems over to Angular 4.  Since the conversion will take some time, we were hoping to convert our components one by one into angular and have angular wrap around our old pages and run as they do now in conjunction with the new angular components. In our current system is run in multiple frames, header, navigation, working area. We are removing frames in our new angular system.

Our old system primarily replaces the contents of the the working area with a new html page which is entirely composed on the server.

I've seen code to launch an iframe from a component.html and then attach a listener to catch onClicks to anything on that frame.  I want to evaluate those click actions from the old system then determine whether to allow the href (etc..) to continue as it use to or re-rout it to the new angular router (ie: this.router.navigate(['/customer']) ) and stop the requested event.  I'm able to get most of this to work, but when my new function runs it doesn't have access to needed pieces of the component, methods and properties are not found. (things like str.replace(), str.match() which are normal javascript methods used in conjunction with regexp , but also properties included in the component, like router.navigate)

Can this be done or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I've also looked at  the alt-angularjs-migration-using-iframes-demo which I run into the same situation.

Here is how I am currently trying to do this:

contact.component.html

```
<div class="iBody1"  (click)="onRightClick($event)">      
<iframe #iframe [src]="'https://www.volgistics.com/ex/Cp.dll?ACT=7' + 
urlUserStr  | safeUrl" (load)="myFunction()" 
id="work1" name="WorkArea" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
frameborder="no" > 


<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
```

contact.component.ts

```
myFunction() {
let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument ||this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
  doc.addEventListener("click", this.iframeClickHandler, false)
} else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
  doc.attachEvent("onclick", function (this) {this.iframeClickHandler(this)} )
}
}

iframeClickHandler(e): void {   
e.preventDefault();

let vars : string = e.target;

let rx = new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g");

let xx = rx.exec( vars );

//    let var1 : String = vars.match(/(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)/g).toString();  // match is undefined if used
//    let var2 : String = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(var1.replace(/\?/g, "").replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}')  // replace is undefined if used

   this.router.navigate(['/customer/100100109']);       // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined 
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.
Rob Thompson

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you in any way, but we have achieved quite satisfactory results with splicing angular on top of an existing application by ignoring angular's routing and just slowly replacing old server-site generated html with angular components.

If I understand your case correctly, you want hrefs from within the iframe to navigate to pages in angularJS. The approach we used was we'd actually let it navigate to the page, and then the html of that page would just be

`<our-new-component></our-new-component>`

which would display our component

Once the transformation is done, you can switch to full angular incl. routing.